# Return Users who have content interactions at least once a week in the past 30 days

Tags: sql, hive

Assume this is what the data looks like - MySQL/HIVE - Assume a week is Mon-Sun

Video_day and Share_day = Videos/Shares of the day not cumulative

| user_id | date | Video_day | Shares_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23672 | 2023-04-26 | 20 | 7 |
| 15021 | 2023-04-26 | 2 | 0 |
| 15021 | 2023-04-26 | 1 | 0 |
| 15021 | 2023-04-26 | 1 | 1 |
| 15021 | 2023-04-26 | 17 | 4 |
| 6241 | 2023-04-26 | 12 | 6 |
| 168 | 2023-04-26 | 5 | 2 |

I need to retrieve the IDs of Users who have any content interaction(Post/Share) at least once per week for the past 30 days. e.g, User 15021 has 0 videos but 1 share - they would pass the criteria for one of the 4 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Group your data by user and number of week, to get which users qualify in each week.

Then group again by user to get which users qualify for at least 4 weeks.

Note that 30 days cover more than 4 weeks and some users could qualify in some of the partial weeks at the start or end of the 30 day interval.

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM (
     SELECT user_id, WEEK(date,1) as week_num, SUM(video_day), SUM(shares_day)
     FROM table
     WHERE date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
     GROUP BY WEEK(date,1)
     HAVING SUM(video_day) > 0 or SUM(shares_day) > 0
) week_report
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(week_num) >= 4
```